# What vintage slide projector can I use to view 70mm formatted slides?

Tags: vintage, slides, projector

1960 Rollei camera, made slides which I would like to view but can't find the correct size format for purchasing a slide projector.

*I've converted inches to mm: 2 3/4" = 69.85mm or 70mm
*What slide projector would these sized slides fit into in order to view?
*Is this considered a medium format?

I'm beyond frustrated as our father insisted on putting our whole childhood on this size slide but no one has been able to view them since they were developed in 1963.
Any information would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Not really an answer, but the next to last comment may give you some clues: http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum27/HTML/005313.html

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment, than an answer.

Is your objective, to project them (On a family reunion)? Or view them.

Probably it is a good idea to digitalize them. You could prepare a setup with vegetal paper and some cardboard and take pictures of them. If you do not have a proper camera and macro lens, probably some close-up lenses for your phone can work. Or maybe a flatbed scanner.

I have not used a slider projector in ages, I do not even use a digital projector either and I have both. The standard method of sharing photos now is over social networks or even a family webpage.

Comment: @Katherine - A commercial scanning service will convert them to digital for around $1 to $1.50 each. Consider time, effort, and sunk cost of buying your own custom equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you beyond frustration? You are talking about standard medium format slide mounts. People are still shooting medium format slide film and you can buy slide film and have it developed and mounted in any decent film lab.

I am not sure if medium format slide projectors are still produced, but Rollei did not phase out their production until around 2015. If you opt for an older, simpler model, you can get a decent projector on eBay for less than 100 US$ or equivalent.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted both answers care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to find a slide projector for 6 x 6 cm slides. I would look for a small enlarger that accepts 2 ½ x 2 ½ film. Perhaps a Durst 6X6. Mount a 75 or 80mm lens on the enlarger. Another way – The camera will work as a slide projector. Open up the Rollie and mount the slide at the film plane. Place “milk glass or plastic behand the slide. Illuminate with a small reflector spot and project the image of the slide on a screen. Don’t foo-foo this – it works.

Comment: Why do you think OP would unlikely find a medium format slide projector? As I already wrote in my answer, there are plenty of offers on eBay. The light source in an enlarger is not bright enough to repurpose the enlarger as a slide projector.